# Are there matrices with same column space but different rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Is there exist some matrices $A,B$ that they have the same column space but different rank? (I do not get if this matrices is $n\times n$ or $m\times n$).

I think that they share the same column space something like this

> A=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1& 0\\
>     0& 0
>    \end{bmatrix}$
>   B=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1& 0\\
>     0& 1
>    \end{bmatrix}$.

Here they have the same one vector from column space, but I do not know is this meaning that they need to have every vector of column space the same or not, what do you mean?

Comment: In your example, $\boldsymbol A, \boldsymbol B$ has different column spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is equal to the dimension of the column space (and also equal to the dimension of the row space). Therefore, the answer is negative.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I try but I need to wait for 20 minutes, sorry